# Пропал автокомплит при написании sass в sublime-text

Tags: sublime-text, autocomplete

Недавно начал использовать sass в sublime-text, так вот скажем при указании какого нибудь background-image пропал привычный автокомплит при выборе изображения. С чем это связано и возможно ли восстановить?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте задать для sass "Open all with curent extantion ass..." css, или установите SASS snippets.